# WPF Extra text in TabControl after ReactiveUI usage

Tags: c#, wpf, reactiveui

I have styles for TabControl worked correct along my project, but there's text in ContentPresenter after ReactiveUI usage.
Current styles have structure like:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
                <Grid>
                    <Border>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_SelectedContentHost"/>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

This is my Main.xml code:

```
<reactiveUi:ReactiveWindow x:TypeArguments="local:MainWindowViewModel" 
                           x:Class="Simlab.Drill.Console2D.Screens.MainWindowView"
                           xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                           xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                           xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                           xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                           xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Simlab.Drill.Console2D.Screens"
                           xmlns:reactiveUi="http://reactiveui.net"
                           mc:Ignorable="d"
                           ResizeMode="NoResize"
                           d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:MainWindowViewModel}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <reactiveUi:RoutedViewHost 
            Grid.Row="0" 
            x:Name="RoutedViewHost"
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
            VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" />

        <TabControl Grid.Row="1" Margin="15" x:Name="Items" TabStripPlacement="Bottom">
                
        </TabControl>

    </Grid>
</reactiveUi:ReactiveWindow>
```

Tab1View.xaml contains markup for TabItem content:

```
<reactiveUi:ReactiveUserControl x:TypeArguments="local:Tab1ViewModel" 
                                x:Class="Simlab.Drill.Console2D.Screens.MainTabs.Tab1View"
                                xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                                xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
                                xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
                                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Simlab.Drill.Console2D.Screens.MainTabs"
                                xmlns:reactiveUi="http://reactiveui.net"
                                mc:Ignorable="d" 
                                d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="Tab 1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
</reactiveUi:ReactiveUserControl>
```

[Here wrong text is framed by red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gsJB.png)

So how this text can be removed?

Comment: Rxui has a view locator system. If a ItemTemplate is not set it'll attempt to find a view in the splat DI and use a default if one can't be found. See the view locator docs.